# C#での画面表示のバインドについて（イベントハンドラ経由で画面を更新させたい）

Tags: c#

ModelView側で以下のようなデータプロパティを持っており、

```
public ObservableCollection<DispData> DispCollection { get; set; }
```

DispDatanに以下のようなデータを持っています

```
public string Test { get; set; }
```

View側で以下のようにバインドしています。

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DispCollection}">
 ～
 <DataGridTextColumn Header="test"  Binding="{Binding Test}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
 ～
```

ModelViewのコンストラクタで、以下としていると、無事に表示できていることが確認できたのですが、

```
 this.DispCollection.Add(new DispData { Test = "A" });
```

たとえば、以下のような別のプロパティイベントハンドラの値によって、
DispCollectionにAddする、もしくは現状のデータを更新したい場合はどのようにすべきなのでしょうか？

```
private static void DataChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
}
```

staticであるため、「this.DispCollection」でアクセスできずに困っています。

ModelViewのインスタンスをstaticにして、Instance.DispCollectionでは…と思って試してみたのですが、
画面は更新されませんでした…。

```
private static TestViewModel instance = new TestViewModel();

public static TestViewModel Instance
{
 　get{
            return mInstance;
   }
}
```

Comment: そもそもなぜ`DataChanged`がどのようなオブジェクトに対するイベントハンドラーでなぜ`static`なのか質問本文から全く読み取れないのですが。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`private static`ですので`TestViewModel`が自発的に`static`にしているだけのように思われますが。単純に`static`と指定しなければいいのでは？

なお参考までにメインウィンドウのビューモデルを`static`に取得する方法を記載しておきます。ただVMからこれを使うのははっきり言って設計ミスです。

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.DataContext as TestViewModel;
```

Comment: すみません。まさに「static」に指定しなければよいだけでした。